# how can I support more than 24hours of time format

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I have a requirement to support more than 24 hours of time format, for example if the time is 25:15:00 then it should return 01:15:00, in java local Time API. I am unable to find solution for this can someone please help me in this.

…

Comment: You could just use the modulo operator: `LocalTime.of(hours % 24, minutes % 60)`

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a _duration_, not a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTimeFormatter.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT)` to git the expected behavier.

`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT).parse("25:15")`

For more information see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle-java.time.format.ResolverStyle-)